Number Theory Problem related to GCD and sequence from an Olympiad
\begin{align}
\mbox{Define}\quad & a_{0} = 2,\ a_{n + 1} = a_{n}^{2} + a_{n} - 1,\ \forall\ n \ge 0
\\[3mm] 
\mbox{Prove that}\quad &
\operatorname{gcd}\left(a_{n},2n + 1\right) = 1,\ \forall\ n \in \mathbb{N}
\end{align}
This is a problem from Saudi Arabia TST $2022$ ( Team Selection test for their IMO team ).

I am solving this for hours but got nowhere , I tried induction by assuming
$$
\operatorname{gcd}\left(a_{n},2n + 1\right) = 1
$$
and then proving
$$
\operatorname{gcd}\left(a_{n + 1},2n + 3\right) = 1
$$
but I am stuck ( not solvable from my approach ).

Thanks for reading.

It’s a very nice problem. I would advise to take a break, and then start thinking about it again.

Since you posted it here, you should know that the solution is of course available. So if you want to think about it, do not post.

There are two well-known facts, one is that many professional mathematicians cannot solve IMO problems and the other is that many times these problems appear on the Internet but without a solution.

Note that $a_n \mid a_{n+1}+1$. By induction, you can easily show that $a_n \mid a_{n+m}+1$ where $m \geq 1$. This implies $(a_n, a_{n+m})=1,$ where $m \geq 1$.
Now, let $p$ be a prime divisor of $a_n$.
Consider the finite sequence $b_0, b_1, b_2, ..., b_n$ where $b_i\equiv a_i \mod\ p \ $  for $0 \leq i \leq n$. Assume for two distinct $i,j <n$ $(i<j)$, we have $b_i \equiv b_j \mod \ p$. This implies that there is some $a_k$ where $i<k<j$ that is divisible by $p$ (Observe the periodicity of the sequence, which forces $b_k \equiv a_k \mod p$ corresponds to $0=b_n \equiv a_n \mod p$.), which is a contradiction, considering the fact we initially proved. So, each of $b_0, b_1, b_2, ..., b_{n-1}$ is different from the others.
Moreover, note that none of $b_0, b_1, b_2, ..., b_{n-1}$ can be any of $0, 1,-1, -2$ because, for example, if $b_i=-2$, then $b_{i+1}=1, b_{i+2}=1,$ which is impossible.
Moreover for every pair $(x,y)$ such that $-(x+1) \equiv y \mod p$, we have $x^2+x-1 \equiv y^2+y-1 \mod p$. So, if one of $b_0, b_1, b_2, ..., b_{n-1}$ is $x$, then $y$ can't appear in the sequence $b_0, b_1, b_2, ..., b_{n-1}$, with the exception of $x=\frac{p-1}{2}$ that leads to $x=y=\frac{p-1}{2}.$
Therefore, we must have:
$$p \geq 2(n-1)+1+4=2n+3.$$
We are done.

Could you elaborate more on your solution? (1) Why $b_i \equiv b_j \pmod p$ implies the existence of $k$ with $i<k<j$ such that $p \mid a_k$? (2) How do you conclude that $(a_n, 2n+1) = 1$? In particular, even if you have proved $p > n$, how do you conclude that $p \neq 2n+1$?

@VTand For the first question, the subsequence between $a_i$ and $a_j$ repeats periodically, so there is some $a_k$ that corresponds $a_n$, which is divisible by $p$. For the second question, you are right, that possibility should be excluded!

@VTand I edited my solution.

Another way. These two preliminary results are easy to prove
► By telescopy we have $a_n+n=a_0+(a_0^2+a_1^2+....+a_{n-1}^2)$ for all $n\ge1$.
►► If $p|a_n$ then $a_{n+k}\equiv-1\pmod p$ for all $k$.
Because $a_{3n+3}+(3n+3)=a_{3n+3}+(2n+1)+(n+2)$, these two preliminary facts yields
$$a_{3n+3}+(2n+1)+2=\left(-n+a_0+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_i^2\right)+a_n^2+\sum_{i=n+1}^{3n+2}a_i^2\\a_{3n+3}+(2n+1)+2=a_n+a_n^2+\sum_{i=n+1}^{3n+2}a_i^2$$ Therefore if $p|(a_n,2n+1)$ then
$$a_{3n+3}+2\equiv\sum_{i=n+1}^{3n+2}a_i^2\pmod p\\-1+2\equiv2n+1\pmod p\implies 1\equiv0\pmod p$$ This means that $\boxed{p=1}$. We are done.
A related question that might be useful for beginners.-(Try to use the Quadratic Reciprocity Law).
$1)$ Prove that all prime dividing $a_n$ is of the form $5N\pm 1$.
$2)$ If $\prod_{i=1}^{i=k}(5N_i-1)^{\alpha_i}$ is the factor of $a_n$ composed by all its primes $p_i=5N_i-1$ then the sum of the exponents $\alpha_i$ is odd.
